# How to Insert an advert banner for every third Slide using JS Composer Slider

Tags: php

Hi I am working on my website and  I want to ADD an ADVERT BANNER for every THIRD Post-Slider.

I have previously used this code in a  loop but it doesn't work the same for a SLIDER - Here is the Code I used previously on another website:

```
  if (in_category(37)) { 
    $post_counter++;
    if ($post_counter == 1 || $post_counter == 3) {

 ?>
```

Let me know if you have any ideas...

Comment: What is happening with this code?  Are you getting an ad after 1 and 3?  You should post the entire loop code.  You should include the image directly into your question and provide more details about what is happening, etc.  To get every 3rd you should use if ($post_counter % 3 == 0)

Comment: It’s fine this QUESTION has been resolved and fixed on my side. Thank you . Apparently I had to edit the APP.min.js file . And now I can run ADVERTS via the slider.

Comment: Great.  Can you post that as an answer and then accept the answer so this question will be marked completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! Yes I edited the APP.min.JS file
in order to show custom adverts on the Jcomposer Page builder...